# Simple combinatorics: Number of ways to pair up elements

Tags: algorithm, combinations, dynamic-programming, combinatorics

I am trying to solve this question: https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/en/problems/view/1616

> It's the end of the year, and finally Rafael is graduating in his
>   Computing course. His classmates decided to celebrate the graduation
>   organizing a ball, where there would be live music, food and free
>   drinks. As all balls, the most expected moment is the one in which
>   everyone starts to dance in pairs.
>
> The pairs will be formed between a boy and a girl, and as Rafael's
>   classmates are so shy, that they decided to plan ahead what the pairs
>   would be. There is only one problem: there are more boys than girls in
>   the class. This implies that, if everyone wants to dance at least
>   once, one or more girls will have to dance with more than one boy.
>
> Rafael asked your help: in how many ways the pairs can be formed, in
>   such a way that all the boys dance exactly once, and all the girls
>   dance at least once

While there might be a mathematical closed-form solution, I am trying to solve it using dynamic programming. I am not quite able to come up with the recurrence. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: What did you try?  Did you already solve the simple cases (0, 1, 2 boys/girls, equal number of boys and girls, just one more boy, ...) ?

Comment: For the most part, "point me in the right direction" is not a Stack Overflow issue, especially without posting your work so far.  ["Can Someone Help Me?" is not a valid SO question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question). This usually suggests that what you need is time with a local tutor or walk through a tutorial, rather than Stack Overflow.

Comment: Instead, post some (pseudo-)code to show what you're working on already, a framework for your desire to do this as dynamic programming rather than the closed-form solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is needed here is the number of surjective functions from a set of `b` elements to a set of `g` elements.

A general formula exists, not necessarily needed here.

A simple recursive formula can directly be obtained.

Let us assume we know the number of possibilities `S(b, g)` for `b` boys and `g` girls. Then a new boy arrived. We want to calculate `S(b+1, g)`.

We have two possibilities:

1. Pair this new boy with a girl who has already at least one partner -> we get `g * S(b,g)` possibilities
2. Pair this new boy with a girl in an exclusive way -> we get `g * S(b, g-1)` possibilities

At the end, we get the recursive relationship

```
 S(b, g) = g * (S(b-1, g) + S(b-1, g-1))
```

When implementing the solution in a recursive way, we have to consider that:

```
S(b=g, g) = g!
S(b, 1) = 1
```

When implementing this solution, pay attention not calculating the same value several times, e.g. by using memoization.